# How to Send Additional Data to Server When using Uploadify when Clicking Upload Button in ASP.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, uploadify

I want use Uploadify jQuery plugin to upload files in ASP.net. But when a user selects a file and clicks the 'Upload' button I want send some additional parameters to the server. I have written this code:

```
     <a id="bb" href="#">Start Upload</a>&nbsp; 
     |&nbsp;<a href="javascript:$('#<%=fuBrandIcon.ClientID%>').fileUploadClearQueue()">Clear</a> 

     <table width="50%">
        <tr>
            <td>BrandName</td>
            <td>

                <input id="BrandName" type="text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>BrandAbbr</td>
            <td>

                  <input id="txtBrandAbbr" type="text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
               Icon
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:FileUpload ID="fuBrandIcon" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
     <script type = "text/javascript">

         $(window).load(

     function () {
         alert($("#BrandName").val());
         $("#fuBrandIcon").fileUpload({

             'uploader': '../UplodyFile/uploader.swf',

             'cancelImg': '../UplodyFile/cancel.png',

             'buttonText': 'Browse Files',

             'script': 'PublicHandler.ashx',

             'folder': 'uploads',

             'fileDesc': 'Image Files',

             'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',

             'multi': false,

             'auto': false,
             'onUploadStart' : function(file) {
                 alert('Starting to upload ' + file.name);
             } 
           //  "scriptData": { 'BrandName': $("#BrandName").val(), "BrandAbbr": $("#txtBrandAbbr").val(), "ActionPage": "Brand", "Action": "Add" }

         });

         $("#bb").click(function() {

             $('#<%=fuBrandIcon.ClientID%>').fileUploadStart();

         });

     });






</script>
```

I want to send the file selected by the user as well as `BrandName` and `BrandAbbr` to the server when the user clicks to `bb` the link. But this code sends empty `BrandName` and `BrandAbbr` values.

Edit: i write this code but i get error uploadifySettings in `undifine`

```
<script>

            $(function () {
                $("#file_upload").uploadify({
                    height: 30,
                    swf: '../img/uploadify.swf',
                    uploader: 'Handler.ashx',
                    width: 120,
                    auto: false
                });

                $('#file_upload').uploadifySettings('name', $("#Text1").val());
            });

    </script>
```

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: What is the purpose of using both uploadify and the .net file upload control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send additional data through `formData`. [return to the Documentation](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadifive/formdata-2/)

**Update:**
Anyway the presented way in the documentation didn't work well with me. I used this code and it's work

```
   $('#uploadify_1').uploadifySettings('property_something', 'value_something');
```

Comment: @ dotWasim: thanks for help me, when  write this code in server request.Params["BrandName"] i get null